# The answer should be valid for any given input

Tags: javascript, sorting, ascii, bubble-sort

Write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence.

1.Each character of the word should be arranged in alphabetical order

2. Words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count

Note: - Word only can have lowercase letters

Example :

Inputs str = "she lives with him in a small apartment"

Output = "a in ehs him hitw eilsv allms aaemnprtt"

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  var word = str.split(' ');
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    word[j] = word[j].split('').sort().join('');
  }
  for (var h = 0; h < word.length - 1; h++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length - h - 1; i++) {
      if (String(word[i]).length > String(word[i + 1]).length) {
        var temp = word[i];
        word[i] = word[i + 1];
        word[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return word.join(' ');
}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment"));
```

ERROR message is "The answer should be valid for any given input."

Comment: What does that error message come from? Your code looks to create the desired output.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What did you manage to do so far? I could write the function but that's not the point of this forum.

So if you give me some more information, I can try to help you figure it out.

Comment: I guess you have some other code executed before/after you are running this methode, producing the error - because the 'error'-message has to be thrown somewhere manually ( as this is not an error coming from the javascript interpreter ) - i would advice to check the script imports in your html-file.

Comment: Please add the test case where the code is generating the error.

Comment: I cheated a bit by putting a console.log() inside the function and it looks like it's failing on the test case `"he was curious about how it would taste, so he took a small bite."` (i.e. one that contains punctuation). It's unclear, however, what the expected result is in that case because the requirements do not indicate what to do when there's punctuation in the sentence. I would say this is probably not worth your time because the requirements are insufficiently defined.

Comment: @JLRishe The expected output for that string is `"a eh it os eh how asw koot .beit allms dlouw abotu ,aestt ciorsuu"`. I too cheated(view:source) :p

Comment: anyone can tell me how to find where the code is failing

Comment: @AakashMore That just raises the question of why that's a right answer, but `"a eh it os eh asw how koot abotu dlouw allms .beit ,aestt ciorsuu"` (OP's result) isn't. Seems like they should both be ok.

Comment: @Ocean I'm not sure anyone can tell you where the code is failing because the task's requirements are incomplete and, as I said, probably not worth your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further reflection, it's clear that their challenge isn't following their own rules. It clearly states:

> Word only can have lowercase letters

Yet, it runs this through the code (with punctuation):

```
he was curious about how it would taste, so he took a small bite.
```

To make matters worse, it expects the following output, which places `how` before `saw`, even though `how` appears after `saw`:

```
a eh it os eh how asw koot .beit allms dlouw abotu ,aestt ciorsuu
```

So, to be able to pass this challenge, you're also going to need to swap words of the same length with each other.

#### NodeJS Solution

The following produces the correct results in NodeJS, but not in the browser, in fact, `sort()` gave me different results in different browsers!

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  var word = str.split(' ');
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    word[j] = word[j].split('').sort().join('');
  }
  return word.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).join(' ');
}
console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort('he was curious about how it would taste, so he took a small bite.'));
```

I then read about why sort is so unreliable, and this article is a great resource, unfortunately, the solution in it provides reliable results, but not in the way this challenge expects it.

https://medium.com/@fsufitch/is-javascript-array-sort-stable-46b90822543f

#### Challenge

http://ccc.fidenz.com/en/challenges/challenges/challenge--86

#### Takeaway

This is a horribly designed challenge, you really should focus your efforts on a better website to practice programming, such as HackerRank, instead of this hodgepodge mess.

Comment: yeap that is the quection

Comment: do you have any suggestion,about how to fix this